# jQuery onclick window.open variable width

Tags: jquery

I'm currently trying to get a jQuery script to take a look at the dimensions of an image which is linked to via the `href` of an anchor. But my current method results in the variable which contains the width saying it's not defined.

The reason I'm having to do this dirty method is I have no control over the HTML, so I'm trying to work with whats here.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="push--down">
    <li><a href="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02883/gameofthrones2jpg_2883318b.jpg">This is a link to an image</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02883/gameofthrones2jpg_2883318b.jpg">This is a link to an image</a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var imgWidth,
  imgHeight;

  var linkedImage = $(".push--down li a");

  linkedImage.each(function(i, el){

    var href_value = el.href;

      if (/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/.test(href_value)) {

        var imgSrc = href_value;

        $("<img/>").attr("src", imgSrc).load(function() {
          imgWidth = this.width;
          imgHeight = this.height;
          console.log(imgWidth);
        });

         //console.log(href_value + " is a pic");
         $(this).click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
         $(this).attr("onclick","window.open(this.href, 'mywindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=' + imgWidth + ',height=auto');");
      } else {
         //console.log(href_value + " is not a pic");
      }
  });

});
```

Note this line is where I reference the `imgWidth` var:

```
$(this).attr("onclick","window.open(this.href, 'mywindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=' + imgWidth + ',height=auto');");
```

**Working example:**
http://codepen.io/vdecree/pen/ykjdi/

Please note that I'm not jQuery pro so this might be kinda messy but it all works apart from this one part—I'm totally open to improvements though.

EDIT*****************

I found that by moving the line that sets the window attributes to inside the part getting the actual `imgWidth` + `imgHeight` — things start to sort of work. But in doing this, it no longer applys it to just href's that have an image.

jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){

  var imgWidth,
        imgHeight;

  var linkedImage = $(".push--down li a");

  linkedImage.each(function(i, el){

    var href_value = el.href;

      if (/\.(jpg|png|gif)$/.test(href_value)) {

        var imgSrc = href_value;

        $("<img>").attr("src", imgSrc).load(function() {
          imgWidth = this.width;
          imgHeight = this.height;

          //LINE THATS BEEN MOVED **********************
          linkedImage.attr("onclick","window.open(this.href, 'mywindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=" + imgWidth + ",height=" + imgHeight + "');");
        });

         //console.log(href_value + " is a pic");
         $(this).click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });

      } else {
         //console.log(href_value + " is not a pic");
      }
  });

});
```

I'm still stumped in the structure I need adopt to get this working

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the variable in the callback, rather than replacing with the value.  The value is only visible within the `$document(ready)` callback, so by the time the click event fires, the variable is undefined.

You can fix this by putting the value of the variable in the callback string, like so:

```
$(this).attr("onclick","window.open(this.href, 'mywindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=" + imgWidth + ",height=auto');");
```

Here's your updated codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjGFB?editors=001

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("img")` instead of `$("<img/>")`.

Comment: If you take a look at the codepen again, I've updated the code and it's no longer giving me errors, however it's not setting the width and height of the popup.